# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from

Tags: php, curl, soap, wsdl, google-ads-api

I am integrating google Adwords API in my web appllcation ,I getting an error while executing my php file i.e

Error:

```
Warning: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in /var/www/vhosts/healthcampaign.in/httpdocs/smscampaign/pages/FacebookAds.php on line 187 
SoapFault Object ( [message:protected] => SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://adwords-sandbox.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201406/CampaignService?wsdl' : 
failed to load external entity "https://adwords-sandbox.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201406/CampaignService?wsdl" 
    [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] => /var/www/vhosts/healthcampaign.in/httpdocs/smscampaign/pages/FacebookAds.php [line:protected] => 219
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( 
                                                        [file] => /var/www/vhosts/healthcampaign.in/httpdocs/smscampaign/pages/FacebookAds.php [line] => 219 
                                                        [function] => SoapClient 
                                                        [class] => SoapClient 
                                                        [type] => -> [args] => Array ( 
                                                                                        [0] => https://adwords-sandbox.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201406/CampaignService?wsdl 
                                                                                        [1] => Array ( [trace] => 1 ) 
                                                                                        ) 
                                                    ) 
    ) 
    [previous:Exception:private] => [faultstring] => SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://adwords-sandbox.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201406/CampaignService?wsdl' : 
    failed to load external entity "https://adwords-sandbox.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201406/CampaignService?wsdl" [faultcode] => WSDL )
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with SSL. If you are testing the API locally and getting this error, try a quick check - find in the AdWords PHP SDK the file named `AdsSoapClientFactory.php` and update around line 142 to add `&& false`:

```
// SSL settings.
if ($soapSettings->getSslVerify() === true && false) { // explicitly disable SSL Verify
```

There are some useful comments below that code line as well. Of course, disabling SSL verification is not recommended for production systems, but at least this can be a quick solution to not lose your mind over why the damn API doesn't want to work.

If this indeed solves the problem, consider implementing it with SoapSettings. Undo the changes to `AdsSoapClientFactory.php`, and in your main file add:

```
use Google\AdsApi\Common\SoapSettingsBuilder;
[...]
$soapSettings= (new SoapSettingsBuilder())
    ->disableSslVerify()
    ->build();

$session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
    ->fromFile()
    ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
    ->withSoapSettings($soapSettings)
    ->build();
```